# C - producent and consumer using semaphores and ring buffer

Tags: c

I have a problem with implementing producent-consumer problem using semaphores.
Actually, the output file is 100% correct - the same as input file.
Although, in Terminal I get crazy things
 [like...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzIKv.jpg)

For me, it looks like the write function always returns value 20, and this is why I can not break the while loop.
I've been thinking about the solutions for hours, and I could not find any...
If you have got any idea, please help, being a newbie is so frustrating.

my consumer code:

```
while(1) {
  block_sem(sem_FULL);
    if(((counter = write(outputfile, rb->buffer[rb->tail], DATA_SIZE)) == DATA_SIZE)) { 
    printf("[c] %d bytes of data saved to the output file: %s\n", counter, rb->buffer[rb->tail]);
    rb->tail = (rb->tail + 1) % BUF_SIZE;
    unblock_sem(sem_EMPTY);
  }

  else if(counter < DATA_SIZE) {
    printf("[c] %d bytes of data saved to the output file: %s\n", counter, rb->buffer[rb->tail]);
      unblock_sem(sem_EMPTY);
    break;
  }

  else if(counter == -1) {
    perror("[c] could not write to the output file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
```

my producer:

```
  while((counter = read(inputfile, Data_in, DATA_SIZE))) {
if(counter == DATA_SIZE) { 
block_sem(sem_EMPTY);
for(j=0; j<DATA_SIZE; j++) {
  rb->buffer[rb->head][j] = Data_in[j];
}
  printf("[p] %d bytes of data saved to the ring buffer: %s\n", counter, rb->buffer[rb->head]);
  rb->head = (rb->head + 1) % BUF_SIZE;
unblock_sem(sem_FULL)  }

if(counter < DATA_SIZE) { 
block_sem(sem_EMPTY);
for(j=0; j<counter; j++) {
  rb->buffer[rb->head][j] = Data_in[j];
}
  rb->buffer[rb->head][counter] = '\0';
  printf("[p] %d bytes of data saved to the ring buffer: %s\n", counter, rb->buffer[rb->head]);
unblock_sem(sem_FULL);
    } }
```

Comment: In the consumer, the last condition `counter == -1` will never happen, because that will be handled by the condition `counter < DATA_SIZE` above it (because `-1 < DATA_SIZE`). Change order of those. Assuming that `counter` and `DATA_SIZE` are plain `int`.